# Why "member.add.roles" doesnt work for me?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have this code rn

```js
async function role(color) {
          let user = message.member

          user.roles.cache.map(v => { return v }).filter(v => v.name.startsWith('MerasuMin-Clr-')).forEach(role => {
            console.log(role)
            user.roles.remove(role)
          })

          let roleColor = message.guild.roles.cache.find(v => v.name === ("MerasuMin-Clr-"+color))

          user.roles.add(roleColor)

          user.send('Your name in '+message.guild.name+' has colorized to '+color)
        }
```

Well i console logged the roleColor variable, and it returns the role that i expected

But... the role is not added
I have tried passing the id of role but no luck

What do i need to fix or add?

Full code

```js
const { Client, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
  name: "color",
  type: "customization",
  description: "Customize the color of your name",
  aliases: ["clr", "cl"],
  callback: async(client, message, args, cmd) => {
    let emb = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setTitle('Colorize Name!')
    .setDescription('Colors Available\n\n1⃣ - Black\n2⃣ - Purple\n3⃣ - Pink\n4⃣ - Green\n5⃣ - Orange\n6⃣ - Red\n7⃣ - Blue\n8⃣ - Yellow\n9⃣ - LightBlue')
    .setColor(0xADD8E6)
    .setFooter({ text: message.author.tag, iconUrl: message.author.displayAvatarURL() })
    
    message.reply({embeds:[emb]}).then((msg) => {
      msg.react('1⃣')
      msg.react('2⃣')
      msg.react('3⃣')
      msg.react('4⃣')
      msg.react('5⃣')
      msg.react('6⃣')
      msg.react('7⃣')
      msg.react('8⃣')
      msg.react('9⃣')

      let filter = (reaction, user) => {
        return user.id === message.author.id
      }
      
      msg.awaitReactions({filter, max: 1, time: 172800000, errors: ['time']})
      .then(goods)
      .catch(gan)
      
      async function goods(collected) {
        let reaction = collected.first()
        
        if(reaction.emoji.name === '1⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Black')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '2⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Purple')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '3⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Pink')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '4⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Green')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '5⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Orange')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '6⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Red')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '7⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Blue')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '8⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('Yellow')
        } else if(reaction.emoji.name === '9⃣') {
          reaction.users.remove(message.author.id)
          return role('LightBlue')
        }

        async function role(color) {
          let user = message.member

          user.roles.cache.map(v => { return v }).filter(v => v.name.startsWith('MerasuMin-Clr-')).forEach(role => {
            console.log(role)
            user.roles.remove(role)
          })

          let roleColor = message.guild.roles.cache.find(v => v.name === ("MerasuMin-Clr-"+color))

          user.roles.add(roleColor)

          user.send('Your name in '+message.guild.name+' has colorized to '+color)
        }
      }
      
      async function gan() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          msg.edit('USED!')
        }, 1000)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the complete error with the stack trace as it might help solve the problem?

Comment: There is no error thrown, it just didn't add the role to the user